# Request Size is too large

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have written the Stored procedure for bulkInsert where I am handling the SP's timeout as well. Still I am getting "Request size is too large" exception while executing the SP. Giving below the SP. Please help me, where I am wrong. I have taken all the code from pluralsight only. and handling in the same way like they have.

```
function spBulkInsert(docs){
    if (!docs) {
        throw new Error('Documents array is null or not defined!');
    }
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    var docCount = docs.length;

    if (docCount == 0) {
        response.setBody(0);
        return;
    }
    var count = 0;
    createDoc(docs[0]);

    function createDoc(doc) {
        var isAccepted = collection.createDoucument(collection.getSelfLink(), doc, docCreated);
        if (!isAccepted) {
            response.setBody(count);
        }
    }
    function docCreated(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        count++;
        if (count == docCount) response.setBody(count);
        else createDoc(docs[count]);
    }
};
```

Code for handling above SP:

```
var totalInsertedCount=0;
                while (totalInsertedCount < data.Count)
                {
                    var insertedCount = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int>(
                                            UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("TestDoc", "coll", "spBulkInsert"),
                                            new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partitionKey") }, data);
                    totalInsertedCount += insertedCount;
                    Console.WriteLine("Inserted {0} documents ({1} total, {2} remaining)", insertedCount, totalInsertedCount, data.Count - totalInsertedCount);
                    data= data.GetRange(insertedCount, data.Count - insertedCount);
                }
```

Comment: How much data are you passing to your stored procedure? Without more details, it's difficult to know the cause of your error. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes! I am passing data greater than 2MB . But in SP I am handling that in isAccepted variable. Also, I can share the SP handling code as well.

Comment: @Shraddha Hi,Shraddha.Please make sure the size of every document is not exceed 2MB first.According my experience, your error is due to the excessive data that was executed by bulkimport at one time. The request timed out and the SDK will automatically roll back and retry. Howerver ,in your code,I suggest you cut your data to import and manually retry against the exception without changing throughput.

Comment: The size of document is perfect. I have added code for sending only 2MB to Stored procedure, it working fine now.

Comment: What I was thinking that no matter how many documents I will give to SP, it will be handled there. But I was wrong. I always have to pass the data upto 2MB only to SP. I think this is my conclusion now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as summary,`The document size in the request exceeded the allowable document size for a request. The max allowable document size is 2MB.` which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb) .

`Stored Procedure Bulk importing data` is a process of executing Stored Procedure, just only one HTTP request, and the size of the requested documents per HTTP request is limited by Cosmos DB below `2MB`.

***Suggestions***:

1.You can split your document data and import them in batches.

2.You can try to simplify your document data, such as removing unnecessary ' ' and '\n' etc.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of where the write occurs (SP or API or in the portal) there's always 2MB limitation for the document size in Cosmos DB. The documents must be split/disembedded/chained/linked/etc on the client side before submitting to Cosmos DB.